# Cordova/Phonegap - Stock an array when I close the app (use them when I re-open)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using an array in my app. Something like that 
[{pseudo: "test", id: 0}, {pseudo: "Lucia", id: 2}]

I'd like to keep this array even when I close the app, how is it possible to do it ? 
Moreover I'd like to use them directly when I open the app (not when it is in background)

UPDATE:
I tried with this,

stockage :

```
 var ami = ({
     idx: id
 });
 var ami_json = JSON.stringify(ami);
 sessionStorage.setItem("ami", ami_json);
```

lecture only launched the first time I open the app (I put it just after my controller started) but I got null value in console.log

```
var amiStorage = [];
var storageAmisNotifies = window.localStorage;
var ami_json = sessionStorage.getItem("ami");
var ami = JSON.parse(ami_json);

console.log(angular.toJson(ami));
console.log(ami);

amiStorage.push(ami);

console.log(amiStorage);
console.log(angular.toJson(amiStorage));
```

UPDATE 2 :
$scope.isChecked is for ng-class, I'd like to take the id of my json but it is like [[{"pseudo": pseudo, "id": id}]] ...
amisNotifies[i].id doesn't work

```
                var amisNotifies = [];
                $scope.isChecked = [];

                var storageAmisNotifies = window.localStorage;
                var ami_json = window.localStorage.getItem("info");
                var ami = JSON.parse(ami_json);

                if (ami != null){
                    amisNotifies.push(ami);
                    if (amisNotifies.length > 0) {
                                        for (var i = 0; i < amisNotifies.length; i++) {
                                            console.log(amisNotifies[[i]].id);
                                            $scope.isChecked[amisNotifies[i].id] = "fa fa-check-circle-o pull-right";
                                        }
                                    }
                }
```

Comment: Read up on the localStorage API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using localStorage instead of sessionStorage

```
 var ami = ({
         idx: id
     });
     var ami_json = JSON.stringify(ami);
     window.localStorage.setItem("ami", ami_json);
```

And also here

```
    var amiStorage = [];
    var storageAmisNotifies = window.localStorage;
    var ami_json = window.localStorage.getItem("ami");
    var ami = JSON.parse(ami_json);

    console.log(angular.toJson(ami));
    console.log(ami);

    amiStorage.push(ami);

    console.log(amiStorage);
    console.log(angular.toJson(amiStorage));
```

Comment: what is storageAmisNotifies, you don't use it after ?

Comment: I don't know, it was in your example so i let it be

Comment: I have something with two [ : [[{"pseudo":"test","id":0},{"pseudo":"Lucia","id":2},{"pseudo":"Gravestorm","id":3}]] How can I take the id of Gravestorm ?